# How to get latitude and longitude of current location in Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to get the latitude and longitude of the current location using the following:

```
 GoogleMap map;
 map = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
 map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

 lat = map.getMyLocation().getLatitude();
 lng = map.getMyLocation().getLongitude();
```

For some reason the last two lines are causing the app to crash due to a `NullPointerException`.  What am I doing wrong?

The biggest thing that bugs me about this is the fact that `map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);` does indeed set my current location.

Thanks to anyone looking at this

Comment: in andorid we have LocationManager for Lat Lang so use LocationManager and get Loi Long and load in google map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. While I am still not sure why the other methods is giving me a null pointer, the below works just fine and will suit my needs.

```
 LocationManager locman = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
 Location location = locman .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
 double lng = location.getLongitude();
 double lat = location.getLatitude();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public Double Lat = null;
public Double Lng = null;
String LatLng = null;
private LocationClient mLocationClient;
```

in your onCreateView() add this

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourLayout, container, false);
        mLocationClient = new LocationClient(getActivity(), this, this);

rootView.findViewById(R.id.ATestButton).setOnClickListener(
        // Get the current location
                Location currentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
                Lat = currentLocation.getLatitude();
                Lng = currentLocation.getLongitude();
                LatLng = Double.toString(Lat) + "," + Double.toString(Lng);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), LatLng, 0).show();
                });
```

Look at my complete [github](https://github.com/kamilagrawala/WhatsHappening) for a working example.

// I would a test button so can click it to see if anything is returned.

Comment: This is causing me the same problem. I must have something else going on. I guess I need to look through all the permissions and everything else and make sure I didn't miss something.

Comment: I still have not figured this out.  What really stumps is the fact that the following line works and sets my current location:                                                              `map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);`

Comment: Remember Location Manager is different to using google maps. You can get the lat and lng from location manager and then use it as you wish. Might be a work around you should consider.

Comment: Look at this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String)

Comment: Yes use it in conjunction with LocationClient. Then you can get the location object returned to you and pull both the Lng and Lat coordinates. via the Location object functions of getLatiude and getLongitude.

Answer (score 0):

`map.getMyLocation()` is null 
you should check for that condition

Answer (score 0):

Your app is crashing because

```
map.getMyLocation()
```

returns null if there is no location data available.So you can have !=null check like this

```
if( map.getMyLocation() !=null){
  lat = map.getMyLocation().getLatitude();
  lng = map.getMyLocation().getLongitude();
}
```

Also this method is deprecated, so you should use [FusedLocationProviderApi](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html) instead. See official documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#getMyLocation())

[Here](http://www.kpbird.com/2013/06/fused-location-provider-example.html?m=1) is a very good implementation of FusedLocation Api, you can check out that too.

Comment: I realize it's null but why?  I need to get the latitude and longitude.  For what reason would it be null?

Comment: may be your location services are off or there can be other reasons that google map is unable to find your current location

Comment: Is there a permission that I need to add that perhaps I missed?

Comment: yeah there is couple of permissions you have to register in your manifest while using GoogleMaps api. see here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#specify_app_settings_in_the_application_manifest

Comment: your device location services are on or not??

Comment: If you have everything setup i.e. location services are on, all permissions are registered and still not getting current location then the only thing i recommend you to use FusedLocationProvider api for getting your current location or you can simply have your lastKnownLocation if location update is not necessary using either Network providers or GPS

Comment: Also you can post your manifest as well to look upon whether any permission is missing or not?

Comment: It can take a while for the device to get a location fix, and until then the current location will be null. You should check the link given above or some tutorials or something, because with your workaround you're not getting the current location. Imagine your user turns gps off, gets on a plane, gets off in some other city, them turns it back on and uses your app. The last known location could be thousands of miles away.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void turnGPSOn() {

        String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
        if (!provider.contains("gps")) {
            final Intent poke = new Intent();
            poke.setClassName("com.android.settings",
                    "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
            poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
            poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
            sendBroadcast(poke);
        }
    }


void getLocation()
{
locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                    if (!locManager
                            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                        turnGPSOn();
                    }

                    try {
                        locManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 10,
                                locationListener);

                    } catch (Exception ex) {

                    }

                }


}
private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            updateWithNewLocation(location);
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            updateWithNewLocation(null);
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    };

private void updateWithNewLocation(Location location) {
        String latLongString = "";
        try {
            if (location != null) {

                Log.e("test", "gps is on send");
                latitude = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
                longitude = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());


                Log.e("test", "location send");


                latLongString = "Lat:" + latitude + "\nLong:" + longitude;
                Log.w("CurrentLocLatLong", latLongString);
            } else {
                latLongString = "No location found";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }
```